# Should I implement a repository and xml service?

Tags: c#, service, xml-serialization, repository, repository-pattern

I'm having some doubts about how to store a simple class like `Person` in a Xml File.

According to my knowledgwe, I've got to create first the Xml service which contains functions like `GetPersons()` and `SavePersons(IEnumerable<Person> persons)`.

And my repository should contain something like the possible queries, `Add` and `Remove` also. I really want to someone explain how can I start to implement these two things? The idea main idea is store it in a xml file and to get some queries from the repository.

Comment: When you say xml service, do you mean web service that uses xml?  If so, is there any reason you need to store the data in xml or can you use a database?

Comment: No, I'm not refering toa web service, it's just the name of a class how is responsible to access the data. That's all

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the Repository pattern is that you hide the details of the data store. So a user of your repository would only see an interface with methods like:

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    void Add(Person person);
    void Remove(Person person);

    void GetById(int personId);
}
```

If you want to use XML as your data store, you should create a `XmlPersonRepository` that implements the `IPersonRepository` interface. Inside those methods you could use the .NET classes to directly access the XML file or you could load your XML data into a `DataSet` and access it in a more relational way.

What would you do if you had several repositories? One for persons, one for products and one for orders. If you then want a single transaction that spans these three repositories and saves the changes in one block, you would also need another pattern. The UnitOfWork.

[Patterns of Enterprise Archicture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) defines a UnitOfWork as:

> Maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and
>   coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of
>   concurrency problems.

Comment: I was thinking that the class which implements IPersonRepository should know in its constructor something like IDataService (if I like to store in a database or a Xml file)

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way. Then your Repository would only be a wrapper around the class that does the actual work. Why add more layers of indirection if the purpose of your Repository is to encapsulate your datastore?

Comment: One more doubt, so when I have to get some data, from where do I get that data? from a variable (loaded previous the data) or from accesing the data..

Comment: What do you mean with 'from a variable' or 'from accessing the data'?You get data from calling the Repository. The implementation of the Repository should be hidden from the user. Your XML repository could access the XML file each time or maybe do some caching.